# "Damn you, autocorrect!" problems

Tags: support

I find I'm constantly plagued by typos introduced by autocorrection. Is that a function of the site, or is that done by my OS as I'm entering text into a field (iPad, usually)?

Comment: Definitely not the site

Comment: As far as I know, there are no autocorrect features on this site.

Comment: Thanks, all. I was afraid of that. Will have to weigh pros/cons and decide whether to disable that "feature". Not at all surprised at the name it has earned ("DYAC"). Sigh.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Theer's no atuo corerct on tihs webstise. Tihs is solely on yuor talbet and phnoe.

Comment: Heh. Nice. Obviously you arent' plauged with it's porbelms.

Comment: Sure, when I use my computer. When I use my smartphone it's a whole other thing.

Comment: I'm soooo tempted to edit....

Comment: Is there a typo in you typo "webstise"? Unlike other typos, it is not a permutation of the correct word.

Comment: @achille: I felt the need to be more diverse than just permute letters around. Also, if you consider the first `s` to be the added letter, then you also get a permutation of the letters too. (And yes, I did that on purpose.)